# is there is any globalization issues using '==' operator and string.Equals() method for comparing a string?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Are there any globalization issues using '`==`' operator and `string.Equals()` method for comparing a string? If yes what is the solution to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `String.Equals`, you can use [`StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) or `StringComparison.InvariantCulture`, With `==` you can't do that.

You should see: [The Turkish İ Problem and Why You Should Care](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx)

Code Snippet from the same article:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
        const string input = "interesting";

        bool comparison = input.ToUpper() == "INTERESTING";

        Console.WriteLine("These things are equal: " + comparison);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above will return a `false` for the equal comparison using `==` operator

You may try the following line in the code above

```
 bool Comparison2 = input.Equals("INTERESTING",
                                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

and the result will be `true`

Comment: This is an `ToUpper` issue. `ToUpper` certainly depends on culture, since in the above case `intersteing` becomes `İNTERESTING`, not the literal tested in the code.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, the point I am trying to emphasis is that with `Equals` globalization issues can be taken care off, with `==` its not possible

Comment: So '==' operator makes globalization problem?Right?

Comment: so using of  assignment operator is not a good practice in the case of globalization?right?

Comment: @Jameel, yes, IMO, you will have problems with respect to globalization in future with `==`

Comment: @Habib So the point is, `==` does **not** depend on culture, the one-parameter overload of `.Equals` does **not** depend on culture. If you want dependence on culture, consider using a `StringComparer.CurrentCulture` object.

Comment: @Jameel, just a correction: `==` is not an 'assignment' operator but actually any equality operator which is [case-sensitive and culture-insensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325.aspx). And yes, it is not good for globalisation/localisation

Comment: then which is the best method for comparing  two string without affecting the globalization?

Answer (score 2):

Both the `==` operator and the `.Equals(string)` and `.Equals(object)` overloads use an ordinal string comparison, and it is independent of culture.

This is different from `.CompareTo` which is culture-dependant.

Comment: It's worth noting that sorting methods usually use `CompareTo`, so setting the culture used before sorting is important.

Comment: is there any globalization issue while using == operator?

Comment: @Jameel The issue is `==` looks at the "raw" string, character for character, **without** cosidering cultural issues. For example `"ss"` and `"ß"` are different with `==`. But there might exist cultures where `"ss"` and `"ß"` are considered equal even if they consist of different `char` sequences.