# c# Dictionary Access

Tags: c#, dictionary

So, I have a  dictionary and I want to get my Object by the "string"-key. It works when I do this:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> entry in myDictionary)
        {            
            if(entry.Key == myStringKey){
                Object myObject = entry.Value;
            }
        }
```

... but throws a KeyNotFoundException if i try to do it this way:

```
Object myObject = myDictionary[myStringKey];
```

The array definitely contains the key. Does anyone have an idea why I can't do it this way?

**Edit:** The class looks like this:

```
public class myClass {

    Dictionary<string, Object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

    public myClass() {
        // Messenger recieves a string-Variable (msg)
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "onObjectClicked", msg =>
        {
            doSomethingWithObject(msg);
        });
    }

    public void doSomethingWithObject(string identifier){
       Object myObject = myDictionary[identifier];
        //DO SOMENTING WITH THIS OBJECT...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

honestly no idea, why that one thing is working and the other aborts the program
[image]

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. `Dictionary<,>` definitely *does* work, so there must be more to it than you're showing.

Comment: Does the key type is `String` in real code or something else? Is that mutable?

Comment: And definitively do show how the dictionary is instantiated, this could easily be a keyComparer issue.

Comment: Define "works." The fact that it doesn't throw an error doesn't mean that the condition ever evaluates to `true`. The loop probably just does nothing.

Comment: This cannot be. Please check the casing of your key. Does your dictionary contains the "same" key with a different character casing ? How the .Key comparison is working then ?

Comment: I don't see any code where you populate dictionary? Did you?

Comment: Btw. the key is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you @SriramSakthivel , TryGetValue worked fine. I still cant explain, why it only works like this. Of course i compared the key and my "string"-value, on the console they showed as the same (yes, case sensitive). i cant rate your answer here, as its a comment... or can i?

Comment: I can't believe this, can you provide what was your key?, cultureinfo? am curious to try it out. If That really helps you may post an answer in my regard and accept it

Comment: Where are you adding things to dictionary?

Comment: yes it works.  As `TryGetValue` returns true, i use now  
` Object myObject = new Object();
            if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(myStringKey, out myObject)) {
                myObject = myDictionary(myStringKey);
            }  `
How can i post an answer in someones regards? Im sorry, im too new here. id like to rate your answer.

Comment: @user Again I don't believe you. If TryGetValue returns true, then [] will succeed. Your latest comment also shows that you don't fully understand TryGetValue. When it returns true, it yields the value in its out param. Simply put, as I already said, if [] throws, then your key is not present. You really ought to try to understand all of this before proceeding. Don't use trial and error.

Comment: Btw you dont need the first myObject = ElementsOnCanvas[id] inside the if, the TryGetValue has already set it.

Comment: Or the myObject = new Object()

Comment: Your screenshot does not back up your claims. Note the presence of That's NOT working in your console. Clearly the [] lookup succeeded. TryGetValue uses the same lookup as []. Why won't you believe that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding values to dictionary in your class, the there is no reason of getting the exception. As a good practice, you should always check for the presence of key before accessing the value. Try this snippet:

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(myStringKey))
    return myDictionary[myStringKey];

//else return something else or throw exception
```

Or as suggested by [Sriram Sakthivel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2530848/sriram-sakthivel) you can use:

```
Object obj;

if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(myStringKey, out obj))
    return obj;

//key was not present in dictionary, take some other measure
```

Comment: This is in efficient. Use `TryGetValue` instead

Comment: Sure we can use `TryGetValue`. I will update the answer.

Comment: You seem be claiming that TryGetValue can return true for a key that results in []. Am I reading your answer correctly?

Comment: Don't know why, but that seems to be working. I'm giving up trying to understand the reason. Thanks @SriramSakthivel.

Comment: @user3351652 Can you post a complete sample? In which you would show us indexer doesn't work and `TryGetValue` works?

Comment: @user Why would you give up?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan seems I am missing something in your question? The function is to check if there is an entry with given key in dictionary or not. If the key is present it will return true and set obj to stored value in dictionary else obj will be null.

Comment: That wasn't really my question. My question was that you seem to claim that TryGetValue uses a different lookup from [].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No I'm not claiming that. It is only a way to get rid of exceptions. The case reported is really strange. I think if we can have a look at what is in dictionary, we may be able to understand it.  Or if OP posts some sample key-value pairs and code some where.

Comment: That would not be an answer to the question then. I really think you should explain your reasoning in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation for

```
Object myObject = myDictionary[myStringKey];
```

resulting in a key not found error is that the dictionary does not contain your key.

Your other code, with the for each loop, might run without error, but it will not assign a value to `myObject`.

Comment: But it does. The console prints out my Object, if i use the loop. thats why i cant think of anything, why the "simple" way to do it doesnt work!

Comment: I don't believe you. And I won't believe you until you prove it.

Comment: @user3351652 Then try to use `TryGetValue` and check whether that helps? also I agree with david, we can't belive this :O

Comment: @Sriram How would TryGetValue help?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know that's bull shit idea, It won't help, internally indexer and `TryGetValue` uses same method. I just want to know what OP comes back with `TryGetValue`. I expected he would say it also doesn't work, surprisingly he came back with "heyy that works" I feel stumped.

Comment: @Sriram suggesting that asker tries different things doesn't help. It gives rise to the idea that the problem is in the code. Simply put, if [] throws, the key is not there. Otherwise it is. There is nothing more to say. If asker would just entertain the possibility that the dictionary class works correctly, the solution would become apparent.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the Messenger object you are using. So I assume it might be a casing issue.

Please try this code: it create a dictionary where key indexer is case-insensitive, and tell us what's going on.

```
Dictionary<string, Object> myDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, Object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

**EDIT**:

The "==" could causes issues with some locales. Have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264057/is-there-is-any-globalization-issues-using-operator-and-string-equals-met) and [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).

**EDIT 2**

I [decompile](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) both Dictionary indexer and TryGetValue of .NET 4.0:

```
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
    get
    {
        int num = this.FindEntry(key);
        if (num >= 0)
        {
            return this.entries[num].value;
        }
        [...]
    }

public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    int num = this.FindEntry(key);
    if (num >= 0)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Both are using FindEntry (which does not use a usual "==" comparison).

The problem you are describing cannot be. Please double check by having both method *together* in your code and have some trace results.

Comment: I don't agree with this; If this is casing issue then for loop also should fail!

Comment: I also do not agree with this, or understand why you suggest this

Comment: SO gone blind? Upvoting this answer? -1 from me

Comment: I'm not so sure about "==" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264057/is-there-is-any-globalization-issues-using-operator-and-string-equals-met

Comment: @Larry It's easy to be sure about it. It is a well understood operator.

Comment: Agreed, and I must confess that the Turkish "==" problem is unlikely. But it worth a try.

Comment: @Larry What problem? Are you asserting that dictionary lookup does not use ==

Comment: No, it does not. I uncompiled this and I found that both indexer and TryGetValue are using the same FindEntry function the same way. I do not understand what is happening -_-

Comment: Why would you decompile? The documentation is clear on the matter. Is that not enough? Also, can you imagine how useless it would be if TryGetValue and [] used different lookup strategies? I honestly cannot work out what your answer is claiming.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Take it easy. I am just trying my best to help this user. I really do not understand what is happening here. Especially when I see the screenshot he posted.